# CMP function always returns jg after comparison in NASM

Tags: parsing, assembly, x86, comparison, nasm

I have the following code which I run online on this [website](https://www.stackoverflow.com/):

```
section .bss
    num resq 1
section .text
    global _start       
_start:                     
    mov eax, 4      
    mov ebx, 1      
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, len    
    int 0x80        
      
    mov eax, 3       
    mov ebx, 0       
    mov ecx, num
    mov edx, 8   
    int 0x80
    
    mov eax,[num]
    cmp eax,0
    jl negative_label
    je equal_label
    jg positive_label
    
equal_label:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,equal_text
    mov edx,3
    int 0x80
    jmp exit
positive_label:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,pos_text
    mov edx,3
    int 0x80
    jmp exit
negative_label:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,neg_text
    mov edx,3
    int 0x80
    jmp exit
exit:
    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 0x80
section .data

msg db  'Hello, world!',0xa,0
len equ $ - msg
pos_text db "Poz"
neg_text db "Neg"
equal_text db "Nul"
```

I want to check if a number that the user inputted was positive, negative, or zero. Basically I want to make a program that let's the user enter numbers until they enter zero (0) and it prints out sum of all the numbers typed before.
So, if the user's input is: "1,-3,3,4", the expected output would be "5" since that is the sum of the above numbers.

I tried doing `sub` instruction to turn the *num* value into number but either I am doing it wrong or it's not the way to do it.

Please feel free to criticize my code, I am a beginner and a solution would be great.

Answer (score 3):

If the user inputs the **text** "1,-3,3,4", then the memory at *num* will hold the following 8 bytes: 0x31, 0x2C, 0x2D, 0x33, 0x2C, 0x33, 0x2C, 0x34.
Your instruction `mov eax,[num]` will be retrieving the first 4 bytes so that the EAX register will contain 0x332D2C31. This value in EAX does not reflect any of the individual single-digit numbers that are of intrest to you, and so comparing *this* EAX to zero makes no sense in the context of classifying the (single-digit) numbers.
What needs to be done is looping over the string while validating, classifying, converting, summing, ...

### This is my suggestion

```
section .bss
    res   resd 1
    num   resb 8
section .text
    global _start
_start:              

    ...

    mov   ebx, num            ; Address of the text
    xor   ecx, ecx            ; Sum
.a: movzx eax, byte [ebx]     ; Current character
    sub   eax, '0'            ; Convert to digit [0,9] IF it is ["0","9"]
    jz    .d                  ; Null '0' provides an early out
    cmp   eax, 9              ; Comma ',' and Minus '-' get skipped here
    ja    .c                  ;  together will everything else
    cmp   byte [ebx - 1], '-' ; Has [1,9] a minus prepended?
    jne   .b                  ; Go add positive
    neg   eax                 ; From [1,9] to [-1,-9], go add negative
.b: add   ecx, eax
.c: inc   ebx                 ; Move to next character
    cmp   ebx, num + 8        ; Continu the loop while not at the end
    jb    .a
.d: mov   [res], ecx
```

You can use next simplified print-out only if the final sum in ECX should happen to be a single-digit number:

```
mov   eax, 4      
mov   ebx, 1      
mov   ecx, res
add   byte [res], '0'
mov   edx, 1    
int   0x80
```

The above code snippet shows that it is not particularly hard to program this task. I really cannot agree with one of the other answers that uses words as:

> If You are a beginner, you should begin with an easier program
> ... it's not easy to do with assembly
> ... and it's also hard
> ... it's also very difficult

Answer (score 1):

##### It jumps to `jg` because:

The input number is stored as an ASCII character, not a number, and for example, if i try to compare the ASCII '0' character (which is 48 in ASCII table and stored as 48 in memory), it will be always greater than the number 0 (which is stored as 0 in memory).

If you are working only with 1-digit and unsigned numbers, you can convert it by subtracting 48 from eax (`sub eax, 48`).

**Your code will not work from this** (it's only a step for a full-functioning sum program in assembly), because there are more difficulties:

- You have to split the input text by `,` characters
- You have to handle the negative numbers, in memory, the negative numbers also stored as positive (I recommend reading this about it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-the-negative-numbers-are-stored-in-memory/)
- You have to solve printing out numbers, because the `write` syscall can only print ASCII characters.

##### The following documents and websites can help you get started:

- Few simple info about x86 and NASM: https://courses.ics.hawaii.edu/ReviewICS312/morea/FirstProgram/ics312_nasm_first_program.pdf
- x86 NASM Assembly YouTube tutorial series: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLmxT2pVYo5LB5EzTPZGfFN0c2GDiSXgQe
- YouTube video tutorial series for NASM **x86-64** from the basics - **for x64, so a little bit different than your code and uses other (64 bit) registers** (this series also contains how to print numbers): https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLetF-YjXm-sCH6FrTz4AQhfH6INDQvQSn
- ASCII table: https://www.ascii-code.com/
- How memory stores negative numbers: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-the-negative-numbers-are-stored-in-memory/
- How memory stores floats: https://www.log2base2.com/storage/how-float-values-are-stored-in-memory.html

Comment: Negative numbers aren't "stored as positive".  They're stored with a 32-bit bit-pattern that has the high bit set, so when interpreted as 2's complement, they're negative.  When interpreted as unsigned they're large unsigned numbers, but `jg` is a signed condition.  But anyway, in the OP's program they're ASCII strings like `db '-', '3'`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I meant, that memory can't store negative numbers with a '-' sign, so we can read those as positive

Comment: If you just mean that the minus sign is a separate byte, say that string representations of negative integers are at least 2 ASCII characters long.  If you parse it wrong and look at the `-` and `3` separately, you'll see a `+3` digit, yes, but the string was `"-3"` which represents a negative number.  Your statement is misleading because computers certainly can store negative integers as 2's complement binary integers, or as strings.

Answer (score 1):

Sub-method only works with 0 ≤ num ≤ 9.

And `mov eax, [num]` moves 4 bytes (4 chars) to eax, because eax is a DWORD (4 byte) register (i forgot about it in my previous answer).

This causes that eax will contain `0x332D2C31` (it's because '1' = 0x31; ',' = 0x2C; '-' = 0x2D; '3' = 0x33 in ASCII, and Little Endian byte order reverses the byte order). Instead of eax, use `al` register (because it's a 1-byte register). So your code should look like this:

```
...

mov al, [num]   ; Move the 1st byte of 'num' into al
sub al, 48      ; Convert ASCII char to number

cmp al, 0
jl negative_label
je equal_label
jg positive_label

...
```

And (this is optional and it does not affect the code, but) you should `resb 8` instead of `resq 1`. It does the same, but it looks better, if you reserve 8 1-byte value (8 chars), instead of reserving 1 8-byte value (= an `uint64_t` in C).

[More about little endian and byte orders](https://www.rapidtables.com/prog/endianess.html).

Comment: This works for single-digit non-negative integers.  It can't handle a `'-`` character; it would do `'-' - '0'` = 0x2d - 0x30 = -3, and then the next byte of `-3` (the `3`) would get detected as positive.  (It's a coincidence that the minus-sign character itself gets treated as having a digit value of `-3`.)